# Is there any equivalent for 'amorous affairs' that is very informal?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, colloquialisms

I'm looking for a way of saying “having amorous affairs”. Ideally it should indicate a married man fooling around with younger women, and the expression should be informal, humorous, in low register but yet not rude.

Comment: Ugh. In one sense this is totally on topic. In the primary sense this is just junk entertainment.

Comment: @Mitch: This can be construed as an exploit, a way to troll the site and excite the legions of bored dilettantes who could not answer a legitimate English question but certainly do have an opinion about what to call illicit sex.

Comment: @Robusto so you're saying the question is educational?

Comment: @Mitch: Most things are, to some extent. The question is, of what value is this particular bit of education?

Comment: @Robusto: The question is plain off-topic here. The OP is asking whether or not they are looking for a word. We do not know that. Only they themselves do.

Comment: The question is absolutely clear, the OP is looking for a light-hearted frivolous term for a love affair. And I really fail to see why some members have taken such a high brow attitude to what is a perfectly legitimate request. If the OP had asked for a hardcore term, crude, vulgar or derogatory expressions I would understand their distaste, but this?

Answer (score 15):

A short-lived affair is commonly referred to as a **fling**

[Cambridge Dictionaries](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/have-a-fling) says

> to have a ​short ​sexual ​relationship with someone:
>   *She's been having a fling with her ​boss.*

Comment: @Josh61 where else could it come from?  The present sense is very close to the 1827 sense, which continues in use as well.

Comment: @phoog now that Josh has deleted his comment, yours seems a bit misplaced. Pity, I quite liked that etymonline comment/support

Comment: Agreed.  The sense was "period of indulgence on the eve of responsibilities," found here: http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=fling

Answer (score 8):

Consider **hanky-panky**. It's informal and it's humorous:

> *informal* sexual activity – *used humorously*

([Longman](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/hanky-panky))

Comment: Yes, indeed. +1.

Comment: Based on the request, I think hanky-panky is the most appropriate answer. Then again, there aren't many things in life for which hanky panky isn't a suitable solution.

Comment: Or if you want a slightly lower register, [**rumpy-pumpy**](http://virtuallinguist.typepad.com/the_virtual_linguist/2009/11/rumpypumpy.html)

Comment: Only one vote needed to reopen this question, which didn't deserve to be closed. Do you agree?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yep. Fail to see why it was put on hold to begin with. Is there a notification for this sort of thing? I wouldn't have noticed if your message hadn't dropped in my Inbox.

Answer (score 5):

The British down-market term is ***[having a bit on the side](http://www.theguardian.com/theobserver/2003/feb/09/features.review7)***

Answer (score 4):

**play around** (SEX)

informal disapproving

(UK also play about) If someone who is ​married or has a ​serious ​relationship ​plays around, they have ​sex with another ​person or ​people:
If she ​finds out he's been ​playing around with his ​secretary, there'll be ​trouble.
[Cambridge Dictionaries Online](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/play-around)

Note that (according to this dictionary) in the US it only refers to infidelity. In Britain it can also be used in other senses.

Answer (score 4):

**Taking a newer model for a spin.**

Since we're talking about an older man married to (presumably) a woman of a comparable age who is (the man) having a fling with a younger woman whom he (presumably) does not intend to marry.

Comment: I like this expression. +1.

Answer (score 3):

'Fooling around' would plausibly be the sort of informal phrase you are after. One might also suggest a man or, less commonly a woman, was a 'bit of crumpet', which usually designates the non-crumpet party as being someone who is having an affair, though this phrase can also be used for liaisons that do not involve at least one significant other having person. Other options might be to suggest a person is canoodling or gallivanting. You might also say that a couple are 'doing the dirty'.

Answer (score 3):

***monkey around***

> : to engage in (indiscriminate) sexual promiscuity.
>
> : to have an extramarital affair or affairs [Definition Of](http://www.definition-of.com/monkey+around)
>
> [***MONKEY BUSINESS***](http://www.definition-of.com/monkey%20business)
>
> : unethical acts; extramarital sexual activity [American English
> Compendium](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=PGdVBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA116&lpg=PA116&dq=monkey+around+%22extramarital%22&source=bl&ots=U0l1YrawwY&sig=eT0Rg6v4MzZdj76c9SDsvr2693E&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCUQ6AEwAmoVChMIyYuJ3J7yyAIVSnAaCh1GlgDw#v=onepage&q=monkey%20around%20%22extramarital%22&f=false)

***mess around***

> : to engage in casual, often promiscuous sexual activity. [The
> American Heritage® Dictionary of Phrasal
> Verbs](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/mess+around)

***horse around***, ***muck around***, and ***perv around***

> : to engage in (indiscriminate) sexual promiscuity.
>
> : to have an extramarital affair or affairs. [Definition
> Of](http://www.definition-of.com/horse%20around).

Comment: I like monkey around. +1.

Answer (score 3):

From the Urban Dictionary ***[one-night stand](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=one%20night%20stand):***

> - Hooking up with someone for one night of sex with no strings attached and hoping to never see them again. It is important not to exchange any personal info with them so they can't track you down and stalk you later.
>
>   - *I had a one night stand with this guy I picked up at the club.*

Answer (score 1):

A recently coined term describing a sexual relationship between two friends with no strings attached is the following:

- **Friends with benefits**: <sub><sup>[Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=friends%20with%20benefits&defid=225256)</sup></sub>
  *Two friends who have a sexual realtionship without being emotionally involved. Typically two good friends who have casual sex without a monogomous relationship or any kind of commitment*.

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/friend_with_benefits) tells us: *Possibly first used by Alanis Morisette for her 1995 song "Head over Feet," although in the original context it seems to refer to a committed rather than a casual relationship.*

Comment: Also useful wikisaurus: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wikisaurus:sexual_partner

Comment: @Nemo yes, those are all good suggestions, but they're also rude, some more than others, and the OP asked for a light-hearted/frivolous/casual term.

Comment: Sure I agree your suggestion is the best, just pointing out some alternatives for people with different requirements. :)

Answer (score 1):

I am surprised nobody has mentioned *[dalliance](https://www.google.com/#q=dalliance)*.